# Convergence of a Sequence in l^1 space

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a,b are complex numbers, and $k\ \epsilon$ N, the sequence $x_k = a+b^k$ will belong to $l^1(N) = \lbrace (c_0,c_1... ) : \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |c_k| < \infty \rbrace$ for which a,b?

a and b being complex is confusing me a bit, as I am not sure of how to generalize an upper limit for the two values for the sequence to be less than infinite.

Comment: The solution is basically the same as in the real case: $a=0$ and $|b|<1$ or $-a=b=1$. This is however, more difficult to show for complex numbers. Start by showing, that $|b|>1$ leads to a divergent series

Comment: Thank you! The idea that proving |b| < 1  for the series to converge helped a lot -- not sure why I didn't see that sooner. I think I have it now!